# Upgraded ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer. Getting an error about System.Text.Encoding.CodePages now

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I inherited a project that was written in .NetCore 2.0 initially.  The version of ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Core that we were using was 1.0.43.  I upgraded everything in NuGet, so ServiceStack is now 5.4.0.

The problem now is that when I try to run my code:

```
var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(dbConnection.ConnectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider);
using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
```

I get an error

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I see in the drilldown for the dependencies that ServiceStack is referencing version 4.5 of the Code Pages.

I'm unsure of what I need to do to fix this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a .NET Core project then it should not be using any `*.Core` packages which after v5, are only meant for running [ASP.NET Core Apps on the .NET Framework](http://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx).

Since v5, the main packages, e.g: [ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer) contain both .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET 4.5 Framework builds.

Given it's referencing the wrong packages I would uninstall all ServiceStack packages and only install the **non** .Core ServiceStack packages.

Comment: So I tried removing SqlServer.Core from my Data Layer Object and removed OrmLite.Core from my DTO (used there for Alias mapping) and replaced them with the non.core packages.  Still getting the exact same error on the data layer.  Only other items referenced are Microsoft.Extension.Logging, the .NETCore.App SDK and my DTO project.

Comment: @SpaceCowboy74 then i’m assuming it’s unrelated to OrmLite which doesn’t have any dependencies to ‘System.Text.Encoding.CodePages’. The Exception indicates it’s used by SqlClient so you could try uninstalling/reinstalling System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.  The reference to OrmLite references SqlClient 4.51 which in turn references CodePages 4.5.1.  I don't have a direct reference to SqlClient in my code at all.

Comment: You could try adding a direct reference `System.Data.SqlClient` if that doesn't resolve the issue you can try referencing ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer [v4.5.1 pre-release on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) which references the latest official System.Data.SqlClient v4.6.0

Comment: Neither worked.  I used 5.4.1 off the prerelease (referencing 4.6.0) and still get the same error.  I'm about to see if I can redo this in dapper....

Comment: I got it working.  I ended up having to change all my items in the app (Data Layer, DTO and the main app) to be .Net Core 2.1.  Doing that let everything run.

Comment: @SpaceCowboy74 ok great you've resolved it, thx for the update. Tho weird as I was able to create the new .NET Core 2.2. [mvcidentity](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentity) project, setup ef, add OrmLite.SqlServer and use OrmLite as normal without issue. I'm assuming there's something dirty about the upgrade to 2.2 as starting from a 2.2 project works without issue.